# PEK-ORD-YYZ - Re-check Luggage in Chicago?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, luggage, international-travel, ord

Baggage checked from Beijing to Toronto (via Chicago) on United.   Will I need to collect luggage in Chicago and re-check for final leg from Chicago to Toronto?

Answer (score 15):

Yes you will have to collect and recheck baggage. You will go through US Customs and Border Protection too.

Step 1 : Arrive at O'Hare International Terminal 5

Step 2 : Proceed to Customs and Border Protection (CBP Processing Area - Immigration Inspection

Step 3 : Claim Baggage

Step 4 : Proceed to CBP Processing Area - Customs and Agriculture Inspections

Step 5 : Connecting Flights/Transfers

> http://www.flychicago.com/ohare/myflight/international/pages/default.aspx

Here is a really neat [visual guide](http://www.flychicago.com/SiteCollectionDocuments/O%27Hare/MyFlight/TransferGuide.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Are you positive about this? In the last few years, when I flew EZE-IAH-YYC and EZE-IAH-YYZ with United, my baggage was checked through to Canada. I had to clear US immigration, but I didn't have to get my baggage nor re-check it.

Comment: @MartinArgerami IAH, United, and CBP have a special system for international-to-international connections where you don't need to collect and recheck your baggage. That's not the norm in the US though, just something they've setup at IAH. The rechecking process is normally quite fast though; it's just a drop-off where they scan the tags and put them on a belt, not a whole check-in counter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When you land in Chicago you will go through US passport control. After that point, you will need to collect your bags prior to rechecking them on the other side.